# BigQuery faster way to insert million of rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using bq command line and trying to insert large amount of json files with one table per day.

My approach:

1. list all file to be push (date named YYYMMDDHHMM.meta1.meta2.json)
2. concatenate in the same day file => YYYMMDD.ndjson
3. split YYYMMDD.ndjson file (500 lines files each) YYYMMDD.ndjson_splittedij

loop over YYYMMDD.ndjson_splittedij and run

```
bq  insert --template_suffix=20160331 --dataset_id=MYDATASET TEMPLATE YYYMMDD.ndjson_splittedij
```

This approach works. I just wonder if it is possible to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Again you are confusing streaming inserts and job loads.
You don't need to split each file in 500 rows (that applies to streaming insert).

You can have very large files for insert, see the Command line tab examples listed here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#loading_csv_files

You have to run only:

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --schema=personsDataSchema.json mydataset.persons_data personsData.json
```

JSON file compressed must be under 4 GB if uncompressed must be under 5 TB, so larger files are better. Always try with 10 line sample file until you get the command working.

Comment: We must have 1 table per day :). it seems that the quota for load jobs is 1000 per day.

Comment: Yeah but imagine 1000 * 5TB means 5 petabytes. Are you serious you want that amount of data on the same day?

Comment: Misunderstanding. Each day System L generates around 30 000 files, in a folder B. From B un script S generates as much as files belonging to B in a folder D. D may contains millions of files. the goal is to agregate files by day before sending them to BQ as fast as possible.

Comment: Pentium10's point is that you can skip the third step (split into 500-line chunks) by using "bq load" instead of "bq insert". The "bq load" command does bulk loads of large chunks of data, whereas "bq insert" is intended for real-time ingestion of small amounts of data.

Comment: And note that "bq load" can append to tables too (and IIRC it does so by default if the table already exists). See "bq help load" for details.